# Difference between native and integrated mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

What is the difference between native mode and integrated mode in SSRS?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is very broad, and I'm not sure what part is confusing you.

Integrated mode for SSRS refers to integration with Sharepoint. Sharepoint can act as the front end repository for report access.

Native mode means that SharePoint is not necessary, and SSRS will provide the front end. Depending on version, this will be over IIS or simply around Windows' http.sys. This reduces license and hardware requirements, and increases simplicity.

So if you have an active Sharepoint farm that you want to use for SSRS, go with Integrated. If you don't have Sharepoint, native is your only option.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326345(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I'm suppose to advise whether to use Integrated mode or Native mode deployment , so i wanted to know the difference between both of them from performance issues , security ....etc

Comment: Stack Overflow questions work best when they have a specific answer: http://stackoverflow.com/about "Don't ask about...

- Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)
- Product or service recommendations or comparisons"
So if you have specific questions, let us know.